# Values not maintained when controls added dynamically using JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2

I am having an application being developed in ASP.NET MVC2.

There is a style option in my view. The user is able to create multiple styles at a time. Each individual style can have one or more Plots.

I am collecting each style information (alongwith plots in it) in a table by adding a dynamic row to it. The newly added row contains all the fields that are in Style and Plots.

Later on when user submits the view i m collecting the styles and plots in a model.

Please look at the images below for clear view

[image: Style Screen]

[image: Plots screen]

Now look at the image containing style information stored in a new row of table.
[image: Table containing style info]

The problem here is that although the values in controls in dynamically added row are visible but the Value property does not actually storing it. Look at the last image that shows the table row controls above but empty values in the code inspected using Firebug.

Due to this problem i am not able to edit the style again even before submitting the page.

I am properly following naming conventions for MVC controls.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks for sharing your valuable time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, i need to answer my own question.

It seems it is an issue related to  FireBug. It does not shows the values in the fields that are added dynamically using jQuery. Although it is displayed in visual but code does not shows the value.

The problem in my case was related to the ids of the controls.